# How to exclude a Jar file from the gradle dependancy in android project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, webrtc, build.gradle

I am developing an android application in which I am using two gradle dependency  and both gradle dependency has **`libwebrtc.jar`** with different version so I want to exclude `libwebrtc.jar` from one of the dependency

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:3.2.1'
 implementation project(":webrtc-android-framework")
}
```

This two dependancy has `libwebrtc.jar` file with different version if I am remove the `libwebrtc.jar` file from the `webrtc-android-framework` module then some classes is not found so I can't remove the jar file so I want to exclude the `libwebrtc.jar` file from the `com.twilio:video-android:3.2.1` dependancy

I am getting below error when build the application

> Error: Program type already present: `org.webrtc.BaseBitrateAdjuster`

Comment: How are you adding these dependencies?

Comment: I have added this dependencies into the build.gradle files not as module

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Please check I have posted the code

Comment: Does project(":webrtc-android-framework") already include com.twilio:video-android:3.2.1?

Comment: I have included "com.twilio:video-android:3.2.1" in to (":webrtc-android-framework") module and remove from the app module

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way enforcing a dependency version:

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.force 'your-dependency:version'
}
```

If you want to exclude the downstream dependencies depended by your dependencies, try below:

```
implementation "one-of-your-dependencies" {
    exclude group:'org.webrtc'
}
```

Or more generally,

```
configurations.implementation.transitive = false
```

Or `configurations.compile.transitive = false` if you are using gradle version below `2.3.3`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don’t want to exclude the dependancy I want to keep both dependancy but exclude the jar file which is contain by the both dependancy with different version

Comment: "org.webrtc" package is not in the dependancy but org.webrtc package is in libwebrtc.jar so using your solution can't exclude the org.webrtc